# Perl process and store unique values in array

Tags: perl

Below is the log file content and I'm reading the log file and grouping it based on the string - JIRA.

```
JIRA: COM-1234
Program:Development
Reviewer:John Wick 
Description:Genral fix
rev:r345676
------------------------------------------
JIRA:COM-1234
Program:Development
Reviewer:None
Description:Updating Received 
rev:r909276
------------------------------------------
JIRA: COM-6789
Program:Testing
Reviewer:Balise Mat
Description:Audited
rev:r876391
------------------------------------------
JIRA: COM-6789
Program:Testing
Reviewer:Chan Joe
Description:SO hwat 
rev:r698392
------------------------------------------
JIRA: COM-6789
Program:Testing
Reviewer:Chan Joe
Description:Paid the Due
rev:r327896
------------------------------------------
```

My requirement is , iterate thru every unique JIRA value - COM-1234 , COM-6789, etc and store the following or immediate details in to individual array like

(for COM-1234)

```
@prog = Development;
@Reviewer = John Wick;
@Description = Genral fix;
@rev = r345676;
```

(for COM-6789)

```
@prog = Testing;
@Reviewer = Balise Mat;
@Description = Audited;
@rev = r876391;
```

If the JIRA value is identical , say COM-1234 repeated 2 times and COM-6789 for 3 times , still push only the following or immediate details to the respective arrays. (i.e. values of the keys 'Program','Reviewer' ....)

(COM-1234)

```
@prog = Development;
@Reviewer = None;
@Description = Updating Received ;
@rev = r909276;
```

I'm very new to Perl and I can manage to reach only for the unique values and not sure how to push  the following values to individual arrays.
Any inputs will be really helpful. Thanks.

My incomplete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "%%%%";
open (AFILE, ""<", ""D:\\mine\\out.txt");
    while (<AFILE>)
    {
     @temp = split(/-{20,}/, $_);
    }
close (AFILE);

my %jiraHash;
for ($i=0; $i<=@temp; $i++) {
      if (($temp[$i] =~ /(((JIRA|SVN)\s{0,1}:(\s{0,2}[A-Za-z0-9-\s]{4,9}),
          {0,1}\s{0,2}){1,5})\nProgram\s{0,1}:\s{0,2}Development/) || 
          ($temp[$i] =~ /(((JIRA|SVN):(\s{0,2}[A-Za-z0-9-\s]{4,9}),
          {0,1}\s{0,2}){1,5})\nProgram\:\s{0,2}Testing/))    {

            $jiraId = $2;
            $jiraId =~ s/JIRA\s*\://;
            $temp[$i] =~ s/\w{3,}\s?:\s?//g;
            #print "==>$jiraId\n";
            $jiraHash{$jiraId}  = $temp[$i];

        } else {
            #print "NOT\n";
        }   
}
print Dumper(%jiraHash);
```

I'm planning display as HTML report in below format

```
Program: Development
FOR ID:  COM-1234

Revision    Reviewer    Comment
r345676     John Wick   Genral fix

Revision    Reviewer    Comment
r909276     None        Updating Received 

Program: Testing
FOR ID: COM-6789

Revision    Reviewer    Comment
r876391     Balise Mat  Audited

Revision    Reviewer    Comment
r698392     Chan Joe    SO hwat 

Revision    Reviewer    Comment
r327896     Chan Joe    Paid the Due
```

Comment: What are you going to do with this later on? Please `use strict` and fix your resulting errors.

Comment: Exactly what *do* you want to store for multiple records with the same ID? The first record? The last one? All of them in an array?

Comment: And what does the expected output overall look like?

Comment: In the previous question you asked you had quite the answer for that. all you have to do is alter it a bit, but the structure of the code is approximately the same @Goku.

Comment: @simbabque : Edited my question for the final output.

Comment: Why do you set `$/` to a value that doesn't appear in your data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like this data should be in a database.

But it is relatively simple to parse it into a data structure. Here, I've gone for a hash where the key is the Jira identifier and the value is a reference to an array that contains hash references. Each of the referenced hashes contains the details from one of the records.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;

my @records = do {
  local $/ = '------------------------------------------';
  <>;
};

chomp @records;

my %jira;

foreach (@records) {
  next unless /\S/;

  my %rec = /^(\w+):\s*(.+?)$/mg;
  push @{$jira{$rec{JIRA}}}, \%rec;
}

say Dumper \%jira;
```

When you run it on your given data, you get this output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'COM-6789' => [
                          {
                            'Program' => 'Testing',
                            'JIRA' => 'COM-6789',
                            'rev' => 'r876391',
                            'Reviewer' => 'Balise Mat',
                            'Description' => 'Audited'
                          },
                          {
                            'Program' => 'Testing',
                            'JIRA' => 'COM-6789',
                            'rev' => 'r698392',
                            'Reviewer' => 'Chan Joe',
                            'Description' => 'SO hwat '
                          },
                          {
                            'Program' => 'Testing',
                            'JIRA' => 'COM-6789',
                            'rev' => 'r327896',
                            'Reviewer' => 'Chan Joe',
                            'Description' => 'Paid the Due'
                          }
                        ],
          'COM-1234' => [
                          {
                            'Program' => 'Development',
                            'JIRA' => 'COM-1234',
                            'rev' => 'r345676',
                            'Reviewer' => 'John Wick ',
                            'Description' => 'Genral fix'
                          },
                          {
                            'Program' => 'Development',
                            'JIRA' => 'COM-1234',
                            'rev' => 'r909276',
                            'Reviewer' => 'None',
                            'Description' => 'Updating Received '
                          }
                        ]
        };
```

From there, it's relatively simple to get a display of the data:

```
foreach my $j (keys %jira) {
  say "JIRA: $j";
  foreach (@{$jira{$j}}) {
    say "Program: $_->{Program}";
    say "Revision: $_->{rev}";
    # etc...
  }
}
```

Comment: I have seen you using `use 5.010;` instead of `use 5.24` in most of your posts, why do you use this?

Comment: I consider 5.10 to be the minimum version acceptable for modern Perl programming so I regularly use 5.10 features in my posts. If I have a need for more modern features then I'll require a higher version of Perl, but I try to keep to 5.10 in order to keep my answers accessible to a larger number of people.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing. Afterwards I'll also keep your hint

Comment: @DaveCross : Thanks a lot for your input , worked perfectly .

Comment: @DaveCross : I'm now trying to get Hash of Hash of Arrays, like keep Development as my first hash and keep the JIRA ID as the 2nd hash and the associated values.Not getting the results.
Could you pls. help me out here

Comment: If you have a new question, then please ask a new question.

Comment: How about if you just replace the `push` line with: `push @{$jira{$rec{Program}}{$rec{JIRA}}}, \%rec;`

Comment: @DaveCross : Thanks again for your valuable time and input.
My sincere apologies, will create a new post in future.

Comment: @DaveCross  Thought the query was related to this post hence will ask on the same thread.If not please let me know will create a new question.

When I try to access the display of the data:

foreach (@{$jira{$j}}) {
    say "Program: $_->{Program}";
    say "Revision: $_->{rev}";
    # etc...
  }
  
I'm facing the message

Not an ARRAY reference at log.pl line 55, <> line 8.  

I tried to get a display of the data like aforementioned format(HTML) but failed to do so.

Comment: You asked for a hash. Why are you reading it like an array? This really should be a new question.

Comment: @DaveCross : Requested in a new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126657/display-format-of-hash-in-perl

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is nicely structured into one line per data item, and since Perlby default processes input line by line, I suggest doing that instead of messing with `$/` or regexps to split the input records. This does require you to remember the JIRA issue ID from the first line of each record, but that's simple — just store it in a variable declared outside the loop, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my %records;
my $jiraID;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^JIRA: (.*)/ and not defined $jiraID) {
        $jiraID = $1;
        $records{$jiraID} = {};  # wipe out any old data for this ID
    } elsif (/^(Program|Reviewer|Description|rev):(.*)/ and defined $jiraID) {
        $records{$jiraID}{$1} = $2;
    } elsif (/^-{20,}$/) {
        undef $jiraID;  # end of record
    } else {
        die qq(Unexpected input line "$_");
    }
}

print Dumper(\%records);
```

The code above reads its input from any file(s) provided as command line arguments, or from standard input if there aren't any, using the `<>` default input operator. If you *want* to read from a specific file handle that you've opened yourself, you can of course provide one.

Note that the code above stores only the last record for each ID. If you want to store all of them in an array, replace the line:

```
        $records{$jiraID} = {};  # wipe out any old data for this ID
```

with:

```
        push @{$records{$jiraID}}, {};  # start new record for this ID
```

and change the line:

```
        $records{$jiraID}{$1} = $2;
```

to:

```
        $records{$jiraID}[-1]{$1} = $2;
```

Ps. The regexps in the code above are based on your sample data. If your real data has other types of lines in it (or variations e.g. in the amount of whitespace), you'll need to adjust them to match those lines too. I coded the script to `die` if it sees anything unexpected, so it's easy to tell if that happens.

---

**Update:** Based on the sample output you posted while I was writing this answer, it looks like you want to group the data by both the `JIRA` and the `Program` lines. That's easy enough to do as well, e.g. like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my %records;
my $jiraID, $progID;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/^JIRA:\s*(.*)/ and not defined $jiraID) {
        $jiraID = $1;
    } elsif (/^Program:\s*(.*)/ and defined $jiraID and not defined $progID) {
        $progID = $1;
        push @{$records{$jiraID}{$progID}}, {};  # start new record for these IDs
    } elsif (/^(Reviewer|Description|rev):(.*)/ and defined $progID) {
        $records{$jiraID}{$progID}[-1]{$1} = $2;
    } elsif (/^-{20,}$/) {
        undef $jiraID, $progID;  # end of record
    } else {
        die qq(Unexpected input line "$_");
    }
}

print Dumper(\%records);
```

Note that I grouped the output data structure first by the JIRA ID and then by the program, but of course those would be easy to swap (or even combine into a single hash key, if you prefer).

Comment: @IImari Karonen : Really appreciate your inputs.Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't handle the final output, but this may be a simplified approach to storing lists of lists for each hash element (ticket id), along with some sample output at the end.  It's not formatted the way you want, but that should be easy enough:

```
use strict;

my (%jira, @values, $ticket_id);

open my $IN, '<', 'jira.txt' or die;
while (<$IN>) {
  chomp;
  my ($key, $val) = split /:\s*/;

  if ($key eq 'JIRA') {
    if (@values) {
      push @{$jira{$ticket_id}}, [ @values ];
      @values = ();
    }
    $ticket_id = $val;

  } elsif ($key eq 'Program') {
    $values[0] = $val;
  } elsif ($key eq 'Reviewer') {
    $values[1] = $val;
  } elsif ($key eq 'Description') {
    $values[2] = $val;
  } elsif ($key eq 'rev') {
    $values[3] = $val;
  }
}
close $IN;

push @{$jira{$ticket_id}}, [ @values ];

while (my ($ticket, $ref) = each %jira) {
  print "$ticket =>\n";
  foreach my $line_ref (@$ref) {
    print join "\t", @$line_ref, "\n";
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
COM-1234 =>
Development     John Wick       Genral fix      r345676
Development     None    Updating Received       r909276
COM-6789 =>
Testing Balise Mat      Audited r876391
Testing Chan Joe        SO hwat         r698392
Testing Chan Joe        Paid the Due    r327896
```

Comment: Thanks much for an alternate solution :)